# Mounting network drive on Raspberry Pi for Plex server

Tags: networking, usb, mount

My background: Newbie to Raspberry Pi, been playing with Linux for years but not seriously and not regularly.

System: Raspberry Pi 3 with OS version 11

**Issue:** I have a network drive USB to my Netgear router using their readyshare setup.  It has all my media files: movies and music.  I can access it fine through my Windows 10 laptop and already have the server running through the laptop.  I'm trying to set up a Plex server to run through the Raspberry Pi so that I can shut down my Windows laptop when I'm not using it but still access my media.

I've read everything I can find and here's what I've come up with, which doesn't quite work.

First attempt, without password, then it asked me for a password but wouldn't let me type anything in, so I added a password, as shown below.

latest attempt:

1. `sudo nano /etc/fstab`
2. Add line `//98.247.32.244/shares /home/heresolong/media cifs password=pw 0 0`
3. `sudo mount /home/heresolong/media`

password=pw, I actually have my router password

After a long pause I got:
mount error (115): operation now in progress

I also tried putting in username=admin,password=pw, got same error

Error search step A: this then referred me to the manual which doesn't mention an error 115 anywhere that I can find.

Error search step B:dmesg told me the following:

```
VFS: Error connecting to socket.  Aborting operation
VFS: cifs_mount failed with return code = -115
```

Error search step C: Tried pinging 98.247.32.244/shares and got nothing, then tried pinging just the IP and it worked fine.  So I took the /shares out of the fstab file and now I get an invalid argument error 22.  Put it back in and I get an Error 115 again.

I'm a bit stuck and would appreciate any help.  Complex instructions with all sorts of lingo probably will go over my head so if you can dumb it down as much as possible that would also be appreciated.

Edit: short note, does it make a difference that my ip is // yet the dmesg message says attempting to mount \

Comment: Welcome to RPi SE. After reading your question, I don't know where to start. For example: Is your RPi operating correctly on your local network?  Is the RPi connected to the NAS via USB or the network? Just as a suggestion, you may consider approaching your task as a series of specific questions - instead of a single question that covers a series of separate tasks. Try to get a clear idea of what is required for an RPi to host a Plex Server - sketch it out to help get a clear idea before asking questions.

Comment: Sounds like this is way more complicated than it seemed when I first got the RPi.  Operating correctly on the local network?  Let's start there.  It is connected to the router with an ethernet cable to provide internet.  I don't have any computers "connected to a network" that isn't just "connected to the internet".  The Windows laptop runs the plex server just by mapping the network drive and then seeing it as a drive.  That's what I'm hoping to do with the RPi.

Comment: Everything is complicated until you understand it :)  So - if I'm reading your comment correctly, what you need is an entry for your `/etc/fstab` file that will cause your RPi to `mount` the NAS drive. There are a few variables to work through there, but probably the key one is: `what version(s) of SMB does your NAS support?` I've posted one possible answer below - you can try that first, and provide feedback if it doesn't work.

Comment: The most worrying thing about this is that you seem to be exposing SMB to the internet - i.e. `98.247.32.244` is a public IP address. Why would you need that? Does your router have a private IP, like 192.168.1.1 is common

Comment: Jaromanda, the drive doesn't seem to as it's connected through Netgear's Readyshare.  In the Netgear admin it gives me either an internal address (readyshare.routerlogin.net) or an external IP (98...).  The router has a private IP but that doesn't seem to point me towards the drive. </br> Seamus, thanks.  I'm back to work today but will give that a shot and post up the results here.  Appreciate the suggestions.